# To rebuild a dataframe by combining two columns into one column by using pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'd like to rebuild my dataframe by combining two columns into one column, for example,

```
>>>df.set_index('df1')  
        0 1 2 3 4 5
df1
GroupA  A D G J M P
GroupB  B E H K N Q
GroupC  C F I L O R   #It is my dataframe.
```

Then I'd like to see my result like below.

```
 >>>print result
    df1     0  1  2
    GroupA  AD GJ MP  
    GroupB  BE HK NQ
    GroupC  CF IL OR  

#which means column0 is combined with column1, and 2+3, and 4+5......etc
```

I only know I could use `concat()` to combine columns and use `apply(lambda xxx...)` to set up a suitable function.

Does anyone can give me a hint or know how to get it by using pandas in python? Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit weird what you're asking to do, but basically we can iterate over the columns in steps of 2 and then call `sum` on a subsection of the df and pass `axis=1`, this will concatenate the str values. One tricky point is that your columns are numbers and when using square brackets in this way it tries to parse the column name as a str which means that `col+1` won't work, this is why I cast it to an `int`:

```
In [32]:

dfnew = pd.DataFrame()
for col in df.columns[::2]:
    c = int(col)
    dfnew[col] = df[[c,c+1]].sum(axis=1)
dfnew
Out[32]:
         0   2   4
df1               
GroupA  AD  GJ  MP
GroupB  BE  HK  NQ
GroupC  CF  IL  OR
```

**EDIT**

A generic approach uses the length of the number of columns to generate the integer indices to index into the columns array and extract the column names from this to perform the selection, this will work for your df and where the df has str names:

```
In [26]:

dfnew = pd.DataFrame()
for i in range(len(df.columns))[::2]:
    col_1 = df.columns[i]
    col_2 = df.columns[i+1]
    dfnew[col_1] = df[[col_1,col_2]].sum(axis=1)
dfnew
Out[26]:
         0   2   4
df1               
GroupA  AD  GJ  MP
GroupB  BE  HK  NQ
GroupC  CF  IL  OR
```

Comment: Appreciated, and thanks for explaining the meaning of your code to me!! However, (as you mentioned) may I ask that if my dataframe does not have number in the column, which the default setting should be something like "Unnamed: 1", "Unnamed: 2", "Unnamed: 3", etc. Will the question become easier then? Thanks. And sorry, I know it is quite a weird question. :)

Comment: yes, I could rewrite it to use the length of the column index using the index, something like `for i in range(len(df.columns))`: col_1=df.columns[i] col_2=df.columns[i+1] and use these col identifiers to index into the df as usual

Comment: Yes it would make the structure of dataframe more flexible! Thanks for editing the answer again. Actually I was imaging there may be something like `pd.concat([df1:i,df1:i+1],i= ...).sum(axis=1).....`, then I could solve my question more easily by using pandas. Anyway, probably I thought too much. :)